# Android SDK manager 22.3 and Google Cloud Messaging Service

Tags: android, cloud

I read uncountable questions and answers in StackOverflow and all around google regarding missing Google Cloud Messaging Service inside Extra in Android SDK manager because I got the same problem, I could not find GCMS inside Extra in my `SDK manager (22.3)`.

And on the same time I read somewhere that now Google play services includes GCMS . That is some what understandable, But while implementing GCMS I definately need the import as ,

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;
```

I already installed Google Play Services but the import cannot be resolved. I tried importing GCM.jar but still the import cannot be resolved. 
What could be the permanent solution for my problem. 
I did every possible way to get GCMS seen on my sdk manager but I could not.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: remove all the .jar from your project and add only `GCM.jar` into u r project and clean and built u r project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCM support has changed from the original implementation, which is now deprecated. The new method, which you have already mentioned, is to use Google Play Services. This requires that  you build a **library project** which uses Play Services and import it into your workspace.

This is described here [Set Up Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install) and [GCM Client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

Note the paragraph :

> Caution: When you add the Play Services library to your project, be
>   sure to add it with resources, as described in Setup Google Play
>   Services SDK. The key point is that you must reference the
>   library—simply adding a .jar file to your Eclipse project will not
>   work. You must follow the directions for referencing a library, or
>   your app won't be able to access the library's resources, and it won't
>   run properly. If you're using Android Studio, this is the string to
>   add to the dependency section of your application's build.gradle file:

Having done this you will have built a google-play-services_lib.jar which you need to reference in your GCM Client project as a library project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got this now.